# Translation between optical and base-frame

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: rephrase of question:
Why will a static transform not work on a data stream where the relation is fixed. Like base-link to optical-camera frame bringing ZYX into XYZ alignment.

Attempting to avoid programming translations. Would like to translate the optical frame to my base-link. When I do this as a static transform I get a funny results. See video.

```
 <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link6_broadcaster" 
                 args="0 0 0 0 0 -1.57  base_link camera_frame 10" />
```

[Video of the result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uufgn84oihwzdhd/ddd.ogv)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102911/translation-between-optical-and-base-frame/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-11-21**:
inverting the child and parent cause a loop error. There should not be a second broadcaster. I am using the kinetics plugin in gazebo. Though I had not done a ros graph so I will do that now. ....AH...you are correct I was transforming twice in another static transformer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Thomas points out in comment. I was transforming twice in another static transformer.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0